# Как в js (jq) динамически создать аксессор?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вот постоянно стыкаюсь с такой ситуацией...
Нужен аксессор, но я заранее не знаю какие элементы и сколько там их будет в аксессоре, на пример я ищу импуты в форме и мне надо их потом засунуть в аксессор чтобы потом передать дальше в другой метод... 
Но мне известны только способы объявления аксессоров непосредственно в коде.. а мне нужно его динамически задать ... 
Вот пример аксесора:

```
var postForm = {
        'name'  : $('#name').val(),
        'phone'  : $('#phone').val(),
        'message'  : $('#message').val()
    };
```

Вот, как я уже говорил я не знаю сколько у меня будет элементов и их имена, я собираюсь давать им имена по их `id` (если это возможно) 
Моно ли такое реализовать?

Comment: Для примера кода выше вам что нужно? Чтобы автомагически оказались объявлены методы `getName()`, `getPhone()` и `getMessage()`, или достаточно методода `get( propName)`?

Comment: дальше масив будет передаваться этому методу
$.ajax({
    type  : 'POST',
    url  : 'feedback.php',
    data  : postForm,
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(data)
     {
      ..
     }
   });

Comment: так не проще serialize() на форму сказать

Comment: @splash58, serialize же в url сериализует

Comment: @Grundy   вот поискал, а то я плохой объяснятель https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: @splash58,  _Encode a set of form elements as a string for submission._ : _single=Single&multiple=Multiple&multiple=Multiple3&radio=radio1_

Comment: @Grundy  и? я конечно, любитель, но у меня вот так прекрасно работает `var input_data = $('#form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
    data: input_data,...`

Comment: @splash58, ну так серверная обработка может меняться

Comment: @Grundy извините, не понял. Может меняться. но это не помешает переменным попасть в массив post. а дальше, какая разница, строили вы массив сами, или это за вас сделали. Судя по комментарию, автор вопроса хочет отдать данные формы в пост запрос. зачем идти сложным путем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

спустя много лет, я таки нашел ответ на свой вопрос

```
var r = {} ; r['some'] = 'value'
```